# Can I create web services with out using any third party libraries

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Can I create a web services only using J2SE/J2EE i.e. without using Third party libraries. I have created Web services using one of the JAX-RS implementation, Jersey and Tomcat server, But not sure about is there a way to create web service without any 3rd party library. Can someone enlighten me in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely you can create web services using Servlet Api without using 3rd party libraries . But it will be tedious task for achieving small functionality .

1)You have to take care of incoming/outgoing HTTP headers in your code . which can be accomplished just by just giving right annotations by using libraries

2)You have to take care of data format sent back. When you say you deliver json back to client you have to write code for josn formatting . which formats your data . this can be eliminated when 3rd party libraries are used